# Suggestions to replace some text in the file

Tags: bash, sed

I am a beginner of bash script. I have a file with the content:

```
Section1 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1)(PORT = 1500)))
 (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = service1)
 )
)

Section2 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1)(PORT = 1500)))
 (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = service1)
 )
)
```

I want to change the port number in Section1 to 1600, and replace "HOST = host1" with "Machine = machine2". Here is the file after the change:

```
Section1 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1)(PORT = 1600)))
 (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = service1)
 )
)

Section2 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Machine = machine2)(PORT = 1500)))
 (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = service1)
 )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: The output suggests you need to qualify your question with "and in Section 2, I want to replace 'HOST = host1' with …"?

Comment: What have you tried?  What was causing you problems?  It seems straight-forward enough.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` with empty record separator:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^Section1/{sub(/PORT *= *[0-9]+/, "PORT = 1600")} 
           /^Section2/{sub(/HOST *= *host1/, "Machine = machine2")} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
Section1 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1)(PORT = 1600)))
 (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = service1)
 )
)

Section2 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Machine = machine2)(PORT = 1500)))
 (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = service1)
 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a mechanical process translating the requirements.

```
sed -e '/^Section1 =/,/^)/{ s/(PORT = [0-9]*)/(PORT = 1600)/; }' \
    -e '/^Section2 =/,/^)/{ s/(HOST = host1)/(Machine = machine2)/; }'
```

In 'Section1', change the PORT value (regardless of the original value) with `PORT = 1600`.  In 'Section2', change the `HOST = host1` section to the new value. The semicolons are optional if you have GNU `sed`; they're mandatory if you use BSD (Mac OS X) `sed`.  This should work with both, therefore.